# What is the cover of the head of a pen called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What is the cover of the head of a pen called in English?

In my native language it is simply called a cover.

[image]

Comment: *Cap* is the one I have heard; another one is *lid*.

Comment: I'm British English, and I would never call it a 'lid'. It's a cap.

Comment: I've generally called it a "cap".

Comment: Has anyone heard "cork"?

Comment: I'm British English, and I would never call it a 'cap'. It's a lid.

Comment: I have always said "top" (UK english).

Answer (score 66):

It is called

> a **pen cap**
>   Do you know where the cap for this pen is?

is an often heard question for small children after they've been drawing.

Comment: I'm an American, and I would definitely call it a cap (as you suggest), not a lid or a top.

Comment: What eloquent and articulate small children you know!

Comment: The apple falls not far from the tree (their Mom)...

Comment: As an American, I would go with "cap" (most likely) or "cover" (less likely but still plausible). A "lid" generally covers an opening (and thus is usually more or less flat) like a lid to a pot; a manhole cover could technically be a "lid" too. "Top" might work, but is somewhat ambiguous (consider "pencil topper", which is either a decorative or functional thing attached to the eraser end of a pencil -- which would be the opposite of a pen cap that covers the writing side).

Comment: I've always called those eraser caps (when they erase, that is) :)

Comment: @KRyan If that sentence comes across to you as eloquent and articulate for a child, I fear I may have some bad news for you about your kids.

Comment: @Kevin That they keep losing their pen caps?

Comment: Isn't that a question asked *by* an adult, *to* a child? That's how I read "question for small children" (and it's by far the more common experience in my house than the other way around). Though it wouldn't surprise me at all if Peter's children are eloquent and articulate!

Answer (score 34):

There are a few different names for it, which vary in preference depending on your locale. I've heard [**pen cap** and **pen lid**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pen-lid), and while doing some further research on this question **top** seems to be a word used as well.

For the most part they can be used interchangeably, though some people will insist **lid** is incorrect. **Lid** is the natural word for me, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have never heard it called a pen lid - as an American English speaker, it's always pen cap for me.

Comment: In British English, *cap* was used by my parents, but nowadays I hear *lid*

Comment: @Greenonline I've never heard "lid" in British English (native speaker, late 30s).

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Really? Well, that does surprise me. We must move in different circles. I personally only use *pen lid*, as would my peers.

Comment: For context, I am an Australian English speaker. I don't think I've ever even heard someone in person refer to it as a *cap*. Not saying that's indicative of all Australian English speakers.

Comment: Australian also; I say, "lid."

Comment: American here, I've only ever heard it call a cap.

Comment: American. I have only heard it called "cap", and the idea that anyone anywhere would call it a "lid" confuses and terrifies me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm English and hear it all the time. Possibly regional variation

Comment: To me a "lid" implies that it has a height:width ratio of less than 1.  Thus a pen has a cap, never a lid unless it was some strangely-shaped novelty pen with a notably unusual closing mechanism.  American English here.  (Why do I think of it that way?  I'm not sure, I think the similarity to the word "lip" and the fact that, for example, you could refer to the rim around the edge of the lid to a jar of peanut butter as a lip due to its relative narrow size.. I realize this type of reasoning borderline nonsense, but it's how I've thought of it and I agree with kundor above)

Comment: Same as @kundor here: A "lid" is *"a removable or hinged cover for the top of a **container**"*. A pen is not a "container" any more than a laptop is a container (yes, despite the fact that they both contain other things). (Fun fact: my dictionary also says a "lid" is an ounce of marijuana. The more you know.) On the other hand, a "cap" is *"a protective lid or **cover** for an object such as a bottle, the point of a **pen**, or a camera lens."* I would say the American term is correct here and "lid" is terrifying ;)

Comment: Never heard anything other than "lid", British English here. "Pen cap" and "pen top" sound wrong to me but I would easily understand them.

Answer (score 17):

In England, **pen lid** tends to be preferred, with **pen cap** also being used. This may be subject to regional or age difference though (Britain has a very high level of regional difference).

**Pen top** would be least common. It would possibly be used to indicate the top end of a pen distinct from its bottom, but very unlikely to be used to refer to the lid itself.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pen+top%2C+pen+lid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpen%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpen%20lid%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest that this isn't at all true, and "top" is by far more common.

Comment: @Jules Firstly ngrams are not always acurate, secondly you don't know the exact contexts (that search could be firing in cases where the context may be referring to the opposite end of the pen or to the top of the pen as a whole rather than to its lid) and lastly ngrams only reflect a subset of written English, not all written English and not spoken English.

Comment: True.  But I've never heard "top" used to refer to any other part of a pen, and don't often hear people use "lid" much, so I'm confident that the result is pretty representative.  I don't think "lid" is preferred at all.

Comment: My (born and bred in the UK) experience would rank "**cap**" most common, followed by "**top**". "**Lid**" would be least common. Without obvious context, if hearing the word "lid" I would tend to think of something flatter: _the lid of a pan/jar/pot of paint_ etc.

Comment: In my experience (also born and bred UK), "lid" on it's own is unlikely, but "pen lid" is the most common term.  I think the bold in the answer is slightly misleading, since both parts are necessary.  Next most common (again, in my experience) would be "cap", which works better on its own.

Comment: Born and bred UK here - "pen lid" would be what I'd use, and hear the most.  "Lid" and "cap" would be followed, but rarely "top".

Comment: @Jules Aside from the occaisional 'cap' I only ever hear 'lid'. My teachers all throughout primary school and secondary school have used the term 'pen lid' (didn't come up in college since we didn't really use pens much). It could be another regional thing (I'm from the south-west).

Comment: 'Lid' sounds really odd to me - 'cap' or perhaps 'top' sound right. I'm in NW England, and in my 60's, if we're identifying the demographics of it.

Comment: @peterG Usually when I run into an issue like this I tend to assume it's a north-south difference, but it could be that the south-west is in the minority here, but there's no way to know without demographics. I'm assuming for now that it's probably not an age thing based on having memories of my teachers saying it.

Comment: A search for "pen lid" leads to plenty of results, including from a [UK national newspaper](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/why-do-bic-pens-have-a-hole-in-their-lid-to-stop-choking-a6856061.html). Personally I'd say lid (I'm from northeast England).

Comment: Confusing "pan lid" with "pen lid"?

Comment: [Here is a Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pen+top%2Cpen+lid%2Cpen+cap&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpen%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpen%20lid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpen%20cap%3B%2Cc0) for British English, similar to the one posted by Jules, but with all three: `pen top,pen lid,pen cap`. Ranking is #1 'pen top', #2 'pen cap', and #3 'pen lid' with 'lid' not appearing until late 1980's or 90's.

Answer (score 14):

I would call this a **cap** in American English.

In American English a **lid** is often thought of as a flat item that covers something. It often snaps or holds in place somehow. For instance, the floppy plastic cover on top of a can of peanuts would be a lid.

A cap has similar purpose to a lid, but it is slightly different in that a cap will typically completely encompass the object that it is covering, whereas a lid usually rests on top.

Webster's defines a cap this way:

> Something that serves as a cover or protection especially for a tip,
>   knob, or end

[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cap)

Comment: +1 for explaining *lid*'s suggestion of flatness and resting on top (at least in AmE), and the "encompassing" of *cap*. These are the kinds of subtleties of meaning that people usually don't think to tell you and can't be found by counting word frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

**Pen top** is also used by native speakers. As in:

> Where is the **top** of this **pen**?

and

> Have you seen my **pen top**?

I've used it on two continents and no one has indicated my dialect usage is not natural.

Comment: I'm not sure I would even agree on *which end* of a pen is the “top” or “bottom”.